# Can wires go under the supply wires in my panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, nec

The only available knockout big enough for my #1 wires is on the right side of the panel.  The new breaker (double pole 100A) needs to go on the left side of the panel.  Can I cross my #1 wires under the service wires as pictured?[image]

Another option is to shuffle breakers around, but I'd rather avoid all that splicing in the box.

Comment: Such splicing is why *it's a very bad idea* to snip down every wire so it can barely reach where it's going now.  Some people think that makes a neater panel but it actually makes an unmaintainable panel.  Best to *leave enough wire so every hot and neutral can reach every breaker in the panel*.  Code has no opinion on this, though some people misinterpret 110.12 and think it says "be neat at the expense of usability". It does not.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- to be fair, the NECA-NEIS for panels does seem to favor the Mr. Snippy approach....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can route the wires under the feeders there is nothing wrong with this. As far as a code reference it’s tough to find something in this case that says it is not allowed or allowed. The wires in a enclosure can even be touching the 1 requirement the insulation is rated for the voltage.  both the main and your new wires are probably rated for 600v so you will be fine.

Comment: Code says you can't cross the busbars (i.e. you can't make a tunnel by leaving 4 breaker knockouts untouched and criss-crossing wires between breakers there).  If it was going to speak about not crossing feeders it would have mentioned it in that section.